# Is it possible to reuse the same RealmObject instance with different IDs to save/update multiple objects in a write transaction?

Tags: android, realm

Currently, we are creating a new instance for every RealmObject that we want to save in our Mapper class.

```
@Override
public Person toRealmObject(Realm realm, PersonXML businessObject) {
    Person person = new Person();
    person.setId(businessObject.getId());
    person.setName(businessObject.getName());
    return person;
}
```

When we create a new one, we collect it into a list.

```
@Override
public void populateRealmListWithMappedModel(Realm realm, RealmList<Person> realmList, PersonsXML personXML) {
    for(PersonXML personXML : personXML.getPersons()) {
        realmList.add(personMapper.toRealmObject(realm, personXML));
    }
}

/*next the following happens:*/
//realm.beginTransaction();
//personRepository.saveOrUpdate(realm, list);
//realm.commitTransaction();
```

Then we save the list.

```
@Override
public RealmList<T> saveOrUpdate(Realm realm, RealmList<T> list) {
    RealmList<T> realmList = new RealmList<T>();
    for(T t : realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(list)) {
        realmList.add(t);
    }
    return realmList;
}
```

The question is, **is the following possible**, can I re-use the same `Person` object instead and change its values to specify to Realm the objects that I want to have saved, but not have a whole object associated with it?

As in, something like this:

```
@Override
public Person toRealmObject(Realm realm, PersonXML businessObject, Person person) {
    person.setId(businessObject.getId());
    person.setName(businessObject.getName());
    return person;
}
```

Then

```
@Override
public void writeObjectsToRealm(Realm realm, PersonsXML personXML) {
    realm.beginTransaction();
    Person person = new Person();
    for(PersonXML personXML : personXML.getPersons()) {
        person = personMapper.toRealmObject(realm, personXML, person));
        personRepository.saveOrUpdate(person);
    }
    realm.closeTransaction();
}
```

Where this method is

```
@Override
public T saveOrUpdate(Realm realm, T t) {
    return realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(t);
}
```

I'm asking this because rewriting the architecture to use the following would require rewriting every `populateRealmListWithMappedModel()` methods I have, and that would be a bit concerning if it doesn't work. So I'm curious if it theoretically works.

Basically the short question is, **if I call `copyToRealmOrUpdate(t)` on a realmObject, and alter its id and data, and save the same object again and again, will the write transaction succeed?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can re-use the object used as input to `copyToRealm`. We are creating a copy of your input object but not altering the original in any way, so reusing the object like you are doing should work and will also reduce the amount work the GC has to do.

```
Person javaPerson = new Person();
Person realmPerson = realm.copyToRealm(javaPerson);

// The following is true
assertTrue(javaPerson != realmPerson)
assertFalse(javaPerson.equals(realmPerson))
assertFalse(realmPerson.equals(javaPerson))
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. I have a bit of optimization in schedule, then!

Answer (score 0):

Yep, it worked.

```
@Override
public void persist(Realm realm, SchedulesXML schedulesXML) {
    Schedule defaultSchedule = new Schedule();
    if(schedulesXML.getSchedules() != null) {
        realm.beginTransaction();
        for(SchedulesByChannelXML schedulesByChannelXML : schedulesXML.getSchedules()) {
            Channel channel = channelRepository.findOne(realm, schedulesByChannelXML.getChannelId());
            if(channel == null) {
                Log.w(TAG,
                        "The channel [" + schedulesByChannelXML.getChannelId() + "] could not be found in Realm!");
            }
            for(ScheduleForChannelXML scheduleForChannelXML : schedulesByChannelXML.getSchedules()) {
                defaultSchedule = scheduleMapper.toRealmObject(realm, scheduleForChannelXML, defaultSchedule);
                defaultSchedule.setChannel(channel);
                defaultSchedule.setChannelId(schedulesByChannelXML.getChannelId());
                boolean isInRealm = scheduleRepository.findOne(realm,
                        scheduleForChannelXML.getScheduleId()) != null;
                Schedule savedSchedule = scheduleRepository.saveOrUpdate(realm, defaultSchedule);
                if(!isInRealm) {
                    if(channel != null) {
                        channel.getSchedules().add(savedSchedule);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        realm.commitTransaction();
    }
}
```

Instead of creating 150 Schedule each time I save the batch of schedules, now I only create one per batch, and it works flawlessly.